# Math: removing a digit from a number

Tags: math, digit

Let's say that I have the following number: `1286` now I want to remove the last digit `6` and end up with the first 3 digits `128` only. I also would like to do this using the number `6` and the number `1286` only as inputs.

Also if there is a c# solution would be great.
Thanks

**Edit:**
I want to do this using a math equation between the 6 and the 1286, I already know how to parse strings, which is not what I'm after.

Comment: At your discretion, you might add the `c#` tag to your question.  Also, as far as I know, your question is a text-scanning question that has nothing especially to do with `math` or even `digit`.

Comment: If you need to ask this question, I wonder if you are a beginner to programming...

Comment: Hi, I can easily parse the string using c# to end up with the desired solution, but actually I'm after a math solution.

Comment: @MohamedTarek: You want to remove the last digit (which can be done with simple integer division `/10`)? Or do you want to print out the result after removing all instances of a certain digit number?

Comment: @nhahtdh I want to remove the last digit continuously until there is no digits left using a math equation. Thanks.

Comment: @MohamedTarek: Use `% 10` operation to extract last digit, and `/10` to integer divide the number to remove the last digit. Put it in a loop until the number reaches 0 (no more digits).

Comment: @ChrisA. It's not a homework it's more like a very complex application.

Comment: In Python one can achieve this by: num = 1234; num % 10 returns the 4 at the end.  num // 10 then removes that number from the end. It doesn't work in JavaScript; I would also like to know how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

please try the below code: (this is done only using mathematical functions, also I don't know C#)

```java
    java.util.Scanner s=new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    int last=s.nextInt();
    int firstNumber=s.nextInt();
    int ans=0;
    loop:
    for(int temp=firstNumber,i=0;temp>0;temp/=10)
    {
        if(temp%10==last){ans=temp/10;while(i>0){ans=ans*10+(i%10);i/=10;} break loop;}
        i=i*10;
        i=i+(temp%10);
    }
    if(ans>0)System.out.println(ans);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string input = "OneTwoThree";

// Get first three characters
string sub = input.Substring(0, 3);
```

`sub` will now have the first 3 chars from the string, the 0 is the start pos, and then how many chars do you want (ie: 3) - this is where the (0, 3) come in to it - if you had (3, 3), sub would equal "Two"

I think this might be what you are looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript: Here is your number:

```
var num = 1286;
```

This line removes the last digit:

```
num % 10; //returns 6
```

And these two lines remove the 6:

```
num /= 10 // turns num to 128.6
num = Math.trunc(num) // num now equals 128
```

Better yet, you could put it in a function, like so:

```
function sumOfDigits(num) {
  const sumArr = [];
  while (num > 0) {
    sumArr.push(num % 10);
    num /= 10;
    num = Math.trunc(num);
  }
  return sumArr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
}

sumOfDigits(1234);
// returns 10
```

Hope this helps.